# Drupal 9 Commerce change the Pay button text

Tags: commerce

I have created Drupal 9 website. On the website we accept donations using Commerce with Commerce Stripe as the payment processor. By default, the payment button says "Pay and complete purchase". As users are not purchasing anything, I want to change the text to something like "Donate Now". I have searched for answers online but all seem to point to the module String Overrides, which is D7 only and doesn't look like is will have a D8/9 option.

Any idea how to change the text in Drupal 9?

Comment: There is a [dev version of String Overrides that has Drupal 9 support](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides/releases/8.x-1.x-dev), but dev versions may have unforeseen bugs.  If you can write code, you can use `hook_form_alter()` to override the text on the payment form in a custom module.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I tried hook_form_alter but it's not working. The problem is that the form ID is the same across all the forms in the checkout process. I only want to target the last step. The code I have in my theme file is `use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    /**
     * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
     */
    function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
      if($form_id = "commerce-checkout-flow-multistep-default") {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Pay Now');
      }
    }`